# cannot open viewcontroller from uitablecell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a uitableview and I want when pressing it to open a new viewController.

I am using this code which works in other classes, but in this one does not.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Row selected:%d",indexPath.row);
    UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SingleCamera"] animated:YES];

}
```

and I do not know why since this is the code I have used so far. It does not play whatever identifier I put, it justs does not go anywhere.

I have also tried this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SingleCamera" sender:tableView];
```

but I am getting `NSInvalidargument` error

EDIT: the structure of my project is this: I have a navigation controller and an initial view A. From view A, i am going to viewB using the exact same code. From view B i am going to view C, inside storyboad using segue mode modal and in view C is the tableviewcontroller that the above code is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this instead:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Row selected:%d",indexPath.row);
    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SingleCamera"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

and set a breakpoint at the line with the `pushView...` to see if the viewController is even instantiated.

**EDIT:**

About the `performSegue...`, make shore you have that segue in the storyboard.

Comment: Yes it is instantiated but still nothing opens:/

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: can u see my edit? what do u mean by having a segue in the storyboard? how can i have it from a table cell?

Comment: You drag it from the cell while ctrl is pressed. You said you've presented the current view in a modal. Is it placed in a navigation controller (if you forgot to do that, that is the problem)?

Comment: My root is a navigation controller and every passing there happens with segues and modal style. Is there anything else I can do? It is a child of the navigation controller if you consider it as a tree.

Comment: When you present your view C modally, it has to be in a navigation controller. So in your storyboard you will have 2 navigation controllers. The first one is the root of your app, the second is presented modally, and it contains your C view controller.

Comment: aa ok. I chosed the sollution with the segue modes. Thanks for the help!!